# How to download an table using rhandsontable in rshiny?

Tags: r, shiny, handsontable

I have written the following server code to display the content. How to download the file after I edit the hands-on table

```
#server 
 value <- eventReactive(input$file, {
   theFile <- input$file
   if(is.null(theFile)) {
    return(NULL)}
 file.rename(theFile$datapath,paste(theFile$datapath, ".xlsx", sep=""))
 Data <- read_excel(paste(theFile$datapath, ".xlsx", sep = ""), 1) 
 Data
})

output$contents <- renderRHandsontable({
  rhandsontable(value())
 })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add an actionButton in ui.R and use it to save the file.

actionButton in ui.R:

```
actionButton("savefile", "Save", width = '100%')
```

To save the file, in server.R:

```
observeEvent(input$savefile,
                {

                   if (!is.null(isolate(input$contents)))
                   {
                       #Convert to R object
                       x <- hot_to_r(isolate(input$contents))
                       write.table(x, file = 'employee_input.txt', row.names=FALSE, quote = TRUE, sep = ",",
                       na = "NA", dec = ".")
                   }
                }
            )
```

Comment: I've isolated the _input$contents_ so that you don't save your file every time you edit the table.

Comment: what is the function of isolate and hot_to_r? Im an amateur, so explain in simple words if possible

Comment: **isolate** - Isolate lets you get the value of a widget without the associated reactivity. No action associated with the widget will affect the block of code. For example, if I had _input$savefile_ within isolate, clicking the button will not run the code.

**hot_to_r** - If I'm not wrong, rHandsontable is a Java based package and you need to run the rHandsontable object through hot_to_r to convert it to an R object.

Comment: It's running on my system. What error is it throwing up?

Comment: No error is showing. When I click save, nothing happens.

Comment: Its supposed to pop up a window to save our edited file no?

Comment: Okay. I got it now. I had a trouble with finding the working directory. Can you help me on how to save it into any folder of our choice?

Comment: @DomJo
I'm assuming that you have a folder in mind. Just give the path in write.table() as shown below:
`write.table(x, file = '**path**/employee_input.txt', row.names=FALSE, quote = TRUE, sep = ",",
                       na = "NA", dec = ".")`

Please marked the answer as having worked for you also. Cheers!

Comment: Warning: Error in as: no method or default for coercing “character” to “NA". Its showing me this error now. yesterday it worked fine

Comment: Whole code?
As far as the error is concerned, if you can convert all NAs to a value of your choice before passing it to rHandsontable, it should solve the problem

Comment: I solved it. The error was because my data had dates in POSIXtc format. handsontable cannot deal with that format

Comment: Great! I did not know this. Thanks for sharing! :)